# Where is the `listen` Function in Node.js Defined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm poking around the Node.js internals, and I came across the following method definition

```
//File: node/lib/net.js
Socket.prototype.listen = function() {
  debug('socket.listen');
  var self = this;
  self.on('connection', arguments[0]);
  listen(self, null, null, null);
};
```

Within the Socket object's `listen` method, there's a call to a (seemingly) global function, also named `listen`.

```
listen(self, null, null, null);
```

Where is this javascript method/function defined?  I've scoured all the javascript files in the code-base and can't seem to find it.

(There's no specific task I'm trying to accomplish here, other than tracing node's execution path and trying to understand the patterns in use deep in the system.)

Comment: Phantom function! I'm intrigued, +1

Comment: @tymeJV and I'm moving slow today apparently (see answer below)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's defined farther down in `net.js`. As of 0.11.5, [it's at line 1089](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.11.5/lib/net.js#L1089-L1121):

```
function listen(self, address, port, addressType, backlog, fd) {
  if (!cluster) cluster = require('cluster');    

  if (cluster.isMaster) {
    self._listen2(address, port, addressType, backlog, fd);
    return;
  }

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Derp, facepalm, nothing to see here.

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/b80d11d46b3b2abff1cf1fe887971ea50fd7d497/lib/net.js#L1088

It's just a function declared lower in the file, which is OK in javascript due to function hoisting.